# c++ - fopen() internally changes my filename?

Tags: c++, c, file, io, fopen

I use `fopen()` in my c++ program and I tried to open a `.aff` file.

I want to parse a file named `car_wheel.aff` and after `if(ifp=fopen(path,"r"))` has executed, it seems the `fopen()` function changes my `path` variable???

I add some detail to my question to the comment.

**code** (since variable `path` is constructed by my code, I put the whole piece of code here, which may seem a bit redundant.)

```
    char* dir = "../kitchen/";
    char filename[100];
    char* path;
    FILE *ifp;
    int detail_level;
    if(fscanf(fp,"%d %s",&detail_level,filename)!=2)
    {
        printf("Error: could not parse include.\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    path = (char*)malloc(strlen(dir)+strlen(filename));
    strcpy(path, dir);
    strcat(path, filename);    // path is "../kitchen/car_wheel.aff"
    if(detail_level<=gDetailLevel)
    {
        if(ifp=fopen(path,"r"))
        {
            viParseFile(ifp);
            fclose(ifp);
        }
        else
        {
            // jumped here and path became "../kitchen/car_wheel.aff1\002"
            if (ifp == NULL) {
                perror(path);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            printf("Error: could not open include file: <%s>.\n",filename);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
```

I debugged the code in my ide, and it gave the filename char array is 
[image]

and there is no `'1\002'` behind my `filename` variable. What happened??

Comment: `if(ifp=fopen(path,"rb"))` try this

Comment: Off-by-one problem, you must malloc + 1 bytes.

Comment: When you allocate memory for `path`, don't you forget something? Remember that `char` strings are really called ***null terminated** byte strings*. You must allocate space for the terminator.

Comment: Is this C or C++ code?

Comment: Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc about casting the result of malloc.

Comment: Why do you expect `'1\002'` behind the `filename` variable?

Comment: `and there is no '1\002'` - what in your code led you to the conclusion that there should be this sequence?

Comment: @MichaelWalz I don't expect a `'1\002'` behind my filename. It is added to `path` after `fopen()` and I don't know why.

Comment: So what is the reason of dumping this variable instead? But it can be anything as the is no space for trailing zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
path = (char*)malloc(strlen(dir)+strlen(filename));
```

You don't allocate space for the terminating zero character. Change it to this:

```
path = (char*)malloc(strlen(dir)+strlen(filename)+1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This does solve my problem. But I was wondering, when `malloc`, does the allocated space automatically set all the char to `NULL`?

Comment: @Jinglei.Y `malloc` definitely does not initialize the allocated memory.

Comment: If you read the manual page - it does not. You need `calloc` instead. Better methods are available when using C++

Comment: @MichaelWalz So do I need to set the last character to `NULL`? If the last character is a random char, why my program perform as I expect now. Is it a coincidence or not? Thanks.

Comment: No matter wheter the allocated buffer is initialized with zeroes or not, you're lacking space at the end of your string, so it's not properly terminated.

Comment: @Jinglei.Y no need to set the terminating character to 0. The strcat() function does this for you. Read the documentation of the C runtime functions.

Comment: Your code would be fine if you had `malloc(strlen(dir)+strlen(filename) + 1`. Without the `+1` your code exhibits _undefined behaviour_  (google that term) and therefore it _may_ appear to work fine.

Comment: @user6060561 Thanks a lot.

Comment: `strcpy` / `strcat` handle the NULL-termniator correctly. But they write out of bounds, because you allocated 1 byte less as required, which is UB. That 1 byte of memory does not belong to you, and could be used by any other object in your program - e.g. your `fopen` call. That's what you experienced

Comment: @Jinglei.Y Please don't forget to mark my answer as the accepted answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use `std::string` and avoid all this nonsense?